# Fastest T-SQL to convert zeros to NULL in multiple columns

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssas, zero

We have some large data warehouse tables.  Our transformation code makes sure all the numeric measure columns use zero instead of `NULL` for T-SQL math.

```
(CASE WHEN NULL or '' then 0)
```

In the last transformation section we need to turn all the zeros back to `NULL` for use in Analysis Services MDX.  Trying to make sure the No Data lines are not showing in the reports.  Previously set to `0` for SQL math because `1 + NULL = NULL` in SQL and we want it to equal 1

```
where as 1 + NULL in Analysis Services = 1.
```

It is taking about two hours to do the back conversion with individual set statements for each column/measure. I am looking for a way to do it in one read through the table/file instead of thirty-three table scans.

Will the following work and will it be faster?

```
UPDATE MyTable
   SET Col1 = NULLIF(Col1, 0),
       Col2 = NULLIF(Col2, 0),
       Col3 = NULLIF(Col3, 0)
WHERE (Col1 = 0 
      OR Col2 = 0 
      OR Col3 = 0)
```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you want to do? Is it that you want to have a result set available to Analysis Services with NULL instead of 0 in your specified numeric columns?

Comment: So how do you distinguish between values that were originally zero and those that were originally `NULL`? Converting  zero to `NULL` and vice versa will alter the results for `AVG`.

Comment: Do you actually have to use an `update` at all? Would using the conversion in a view on the table and using this view as the base for the fact table in Analysis Services (or doing the conversion in a named query in the DSV) not save the time for the update of the table?

Answer (score 1):

How do you know that it will not be fast enough? did you do any bench marking? You can as well use `CASE` condition like below but per [MSDN Spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx) both are same. Which states that:

> NULLIF is equivalent to a searched CASE expression in which the two
>   expressions are equal and the resulting expression is NULL.

```
UPDATE MyTable 
SET Col1 = CASE WHEN Col1 = 0 THEN NULL END, 
Col2 = CASE WHEN Col2 = 0 THEN NULL END, 
Col3 = CASE WHEN Col3 = 0 THEN NULL END 
WHERE (Col1 = 0 OR Col2 = 0 OR Col3 = 0)
```